# Generating the Linux kernel .config file is making the source folder unclean

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am currently trying to rebuild a linux kernel, and I'm experimenting some difficulties.

I have modified the .config using make menuconfig.

```
...
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/doe/build/linux'
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  GEN     ./Makefile
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  Using /home/doe/workspace/linux as source for kernel
  /home/doe/workspace/linux is not clean, please run 'make mrproper'
  in the '/home/doe/workspace/linux' directory.
/home/doe/workspace/linux/Makefile:1027: recipe for target 'prepare3' failed
make[1]: *** [prepare3] Error 1
...
```

Then I tried to run make mrproper. It works well and deletes my .config file from my build folder. Without surprise I cannot build because a .config file is missing.

I did a make defconfig followed by a make -j 8, just to try to build with some basic config file.

```
  ...
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
  HOSTCC  arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o
  HOSTCC  arch/x86/tools/relocs_64.o
  HOSTCC  arch/x86/tools/relocs_common.o
  Using /home/doe/workspace/linux as source for kernel
  /home/doe/workspace/linux is not clean, please run 'make mrproper'
  in the '/home/doe/workspace/linux' directory.
/home/doe/workspace/linux/Makefile:1027: recipe for target 'prepare3' failed
make[1]: *** [prepare3] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  HOSTLD  arch/x86/tools/relocs
make[1]: *** wait: No child processes.  Stop.
Makefile:152: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

How am I supposed to build if generating a .config makes the source folder unclean ?

Comment: I am suspecting it may be due to some `env` setup. *During the `make menuconfig` why it is entering into the path `/home/doe/build/linux` instead of `/home/doe/workspace/linux`?*. One more thing it is always recommended that you have to also specify the arch name (like  `make ARCH=x86_64 menuconfig`) as well if you have not exported.

Comment: `export ARCH=<ARCH>; git clean -xfd && make <WHATEVER>_defconfig && make -j8` (`<WHATEVER>` is a name of your actual defcofnig, and `<ARCH>` is the architecture in use, you also might need to `export CROSS_COMPILE=...` first.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the "`include/config`" directory  exists in your kernel source.

The `prepare3` target checks the '`.config`' file and the '`include/config`' directory. You could find this by searching "`prepare3`" in the Makefile